# How do I edit the VeraCrypt XML config file in PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to make a powershell script that edits the UseSecureDesktop setting in the VeraCrypt Configuration.xml. The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VeraCrypt>
    <configuration>
        <config key="OpenExplorerWindowAfterMount">0</config>
        <config key="UseDifferentTrayIconIfVolumesMounted">1</config>
        <config key="SaveVolumeHistory">0</config>
        <config key="CachePasswords">0</config>
        <config key="CachePasswordDuringMultipleMount">0</config>
        <config key="WipePasswordCacheOnExit">0</config>
        <config key="WipeCacheOnAutoDismount">1</config>
        <config key="IncludePimInCache">1</config>
        <config key="TryEmptyPasswordWhenKeyfileUsed">0</config>
        <config key="StartOnLogon">1</config>
        <config key="MountDevicesOnLogon">0</config>
        <config key="MountFavoritesOnLogon">1</config>
        <config key="MountVolumesReadOnly">0</config>
        <config key="MountVolumesRemovable">0</config>
        <config key="PreserveTimestamps">0</config>
        <config key="ShowDisconnectedNetworkDrives">0</config>
        <config key="HideWaitingDialog">0</config>
        <config key="UseSecureDesktop">0</config>
        <config key="UseLegacyMaxPasswordLength">0</config>
        <config key="EnableBackgroundTask">1</config>
```

I am currently loading the XML [xml](Get-Content -Path $path) as shown below.

```
$path = "$Env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\VeraCrypt\Configuration.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $path)
```

I can get to a point where running `$xml.VeraCrypt.configuration.config` outputs the following:

```
key                                  #text
---                                  -----
OpenExplorerWindowAfterMount         0
UseDifferentTrayIconIfVolumesMounted 1
SaveVolumeHistory                    0
CachePasswords                       0
CachePasswordDuringMultipleMount     0
WipePasswordCacheOnExit              0
WipeCacheOnAutoDismount              1
IncludePimInCache                    1
TryEmptyPasswordWhenKeyfileUsed      0
StartOnLogon                         1
MountDevicesOnLogon                  0
MountFavoritesOnLogon                1
MountVolumesReadOnly                 0
MountVolumesRemovable                0
PreserveTimestamps                   0
ShowDisconnectedNetworkDrives        0
HideWaitingDialog                    0
UseSecureDesktop                     0
UseLegacyMaxPasswordLength           0
```

How do I find and change the value of UseSecureDesktop?

Comment: You can filter it with [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.4) based on the `key` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
($xml.VeraCrypt.configuration.config | Where-Object {$PSItem.key -eq 'UseSecureDesktop'} ).'#text' = 1

$xml.Save('.\test.xml')
```

Where-Object is really powerfull when working in such tables

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. I just had to change 1 to '1' since it is a text value.